# replace the character ' for "" in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I am trying to write it like this:

```
str.replace("'", """)
```

but it gives me an syntax error, how to properly write this?

Comment: where is the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use escape `str.replace("'", "\"")`